# RadioGroup children not responding to visibility changes

Tags: android, radio-button, radio-group, android-transitions

I'm facing a weird issue with the support version of Transitions.

I have 3 RadioGroups with two children each, I need to sequentially make disappear one of them and appear another one in the same position. The visibility change works fine for the drawable but the text and the RadioButton do not dissapear.

I have this code inside a CardView

```
       <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        card_view:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/card_view1"
        card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/card_view2"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFF"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/containerCardview"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/RadioGroup1"
                android:id="@+id/TextViewPago"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/pref_login" />
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/RadioGroupTipo"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TextViewPago"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/RadioGroup2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/ProfesionalUser"
                    android:text="@string/ProfesionalUser"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_medico"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/FamiliarUser"
                    android:text="@string/FamiliarUser"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_familia"/>
            </RadioGroup>

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/RadioGroup1"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/TextViewPago"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/RadioGroup2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/YoungUser"
                    android:text="@string/YoungUser"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_hermano"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/OldUser"
                    android:text="@string/OldUser"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_abuelo"/>

            </RadioGroup>

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/RadioGroup1"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/sign_in_button"
                android:id="@+id/RadioGroup2"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/MaleUser"
                    android:text="@string/MaleUser"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/nino"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/FemaleUser"
                    android:text="@string/FemaleUser"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/nina"/>
            </RadioGroup>


            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/RadioGroup2"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                card_view:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/RadioGroup2"
                card_view:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:id="@+id/BotonContacto"
                android:text="@string/cont_ctanos"/>

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And this is the code I'm using to switch visibilty is this

```
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup radioGroup, int i) {

    switch (radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
        case R.id.ProfesionalUser:
            SingIn.setEnabled(true);
            break;

        case R.id.FamiliarUser:
            //Animaciones
            android.support.transition.Transition fade = new Fade(Fade.OUT);
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(RadioGroupTipo,fade);
            RadioGroupTipo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            RadioGroupTipo.requestLayout();


            android.support.transition.Transition fadeEdad = new Fade(Fade.IN);
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(RadioGroupEdad,fadeEdad);
            RadioGroupEdad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RadioGroupEdad.requestLayout();

            break;
        case R.id.MaleUser:
            SingIn.setEnabled(true);

            break;
        case R.id.FemaleUser:
            SingIn.setEnabled(true);

            break;
        case R.id.YoungUser:
            android.support.transition.Transition fadeSexo = new Fade(Fade.IN);
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(RadioGroupSexo,fadeSexo);
            RadioGroupSexo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RadioGroupSexo.requestLayout();
            break;
        case R.id.OldUser:
            android.support.transition.Transition fadeSexo1 = new Fade(Fade.IN);
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(RadioGroupSexo,fadeSexo1);
            RadioGroupSexo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            RadioGroupSexo.requestLayout();
            break;
    }
}
```

I've tried with requestLayout and many other weird worksarounds.

Any help?

Here is a picture of how it looks at the end:

[image]